# Как сделать удаление файлов не просто с БД а с сервера тоже?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Как сделать удаление файлов не просто с БД а с сервера тоже?

Этот скрипт удаляем файл.

```
if(isset($_POST['del_prodyct'])){
      $id=$_POST['id_prod'];
         $querydelete_category = "DELETE FROM add_photos_store WHERE id=$id";
         $result = mysql_query($querydelete_category);
         header("Location: /admin/admin.php?page=add_photos_store");
      }
```

Это скрипт для загрузки файлов на сервер.

```
 $query1 = "SELECT max(id) from stores";
            $result = mysql_query($query1);
            $line = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $max = $line['max(id)'];

      foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
          $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
          $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
          $kod=uniqid();
          move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "images/catalog_gallery/".$kod.$name);
          img_resize("images/catalog_gallery/".$kod.$name, "images/catalog_gallery/prew/".$kod.$name, $params);

          $imgmedia="images/catalog_gallery/".$kod.$name;
          $imgmediaprew="images/catalog_gallery/prew/".$kod.$name;

          $queryup = "UPDATE stores SET url_img = '{$imgmedia}', prew_img = '{$imgmediaprew}' WHERE id = $max";
          $result = mysql_query($queryup);
                }
          }
    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно воспользоваться функцией `unlink`: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unlink.php

И добавить запрос на получение пути к ранее загруженному файлу в коде:

```
if(isset($_POST['del_prodyct'])){
      $id=$_POST['id_prod'];
         // тут получить запись из БД с путём к загруженному файлу
         unlink(/* путь к файлу, который нужно удалить */); 

         $querydelete_category = "DELETE FROM add_photos_store WHERE id=$id";
         $result = mysql_query($querydelete_category);
         header("Location: /admin/admin.php?page=add_photos_store");
      }
```